# Como criar um array com resultados obtidos atraves de um observable<any[]> TYPESCRIPT

Tags: firebase, angular, typescript, firebase-database

Bem,eu obtenho um array de chaves,que uso para pesquisar no firebase:

```
addprd(a:string){
 this.prdarray.push(a);
}
```

Depois de adicionar as chaves que quero usar na pesquisa eu uso o seguinte medoto:

```
queryProd(as:string){
  const prdN :Observable<any[]>= this.db.list(`/Produto/${as}`).valueChanges();
  return prdN;
}
```

Retornando assim um observable dessa chave,como consigo fazer um "for" e armazenar um array de resultados para exibir no meu HTML?

Comment: você ja fez um *ngFor no html para testar se é isso que queria?

Comment: eu preciso do array de resultados para exibir,queryProd retorna a consulta de uma chave,eu preciso de um array com o resultado de cada chave,depois eu usarei o *ngFor no html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim:

No service:

```
queryProd(as:string){
  return this.db.list(`/Produto/${as}`);
}

getItems(ids: string[]): Observable<Item> {
 return from(ids).pipe(
    mergeMap(id => <Observable<Item>> this.queryProd(id ))
  );
}
```

No Componente:

```
produtos:Produto[] = [];
ids: string[] = [];

constructor(private seuServico:seuServico){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.seuServico.getItems(ids).subscribe(item=>produtos.push(item));            
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor='let produto of produtos'>
    {{produto.preco}}
</div>
```

Comment: mas assim eu não armazenarei apenas um produto dentro de produtos$:Observable<Produto[]>;? eu preciso armazenar varios,afinal tenho um array de chaves,onde cada um corresponde a um produto

Comment: Nao vc terá um array dentro do observable, o ngFor percorre o array.

Comment: assim,o meu queryProd retorna um produto(no caso um observable) apenas,que corresponde a chave que passo por parâmetro,eu tenho um array de chaves,e precisaria de um array de resultados correspondentes

Comment: Tem como vc editar sua pergunta então?

Comment: Uma duvida a ordem das chaves importa?

Comment: Edito sim,pode sugerir que eu edito,a ordem em si não,mas precisa ser apenas as que estão em um certo array,elas correspondem a um formulário,onde ele seleciona apenas algumas chaves

Comment: Tenta ali minha ultima edição.

Comment: ERRO: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Mas o array realmente ta armazenando,só não esta exibindo no html

Comment: tenta ali inicializar o array vazio

Comment: O tipo 'Observable<any>' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'Produto[]', o db.list retorna um  Observable<[]{}>

Comment: Tente colocar o "| async" e deu certo,mas só ta exibindo o ultimo inserido

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k2h53r

Comment: sim ele vai disparar um pra cada por isso que tem que dar um subscribe e pushar ele dentro do array produtos, ai nao precisa do async pipe.

Comment: poxa deu certo :),como eu faria pra inserir esse id ao array? pra na hora de exibir eu ter o ID tambem

Comment: faz outra pergunta se não aqui vai ficar muito comprido.

Comment: Consegui já,de todo modo muito obrigado,vc mais que resolveu,ate me fez entender como funciona :)

Answer (score 1):

Um observable é só uma declaração da sua consulta à um serviço, para você de fato ter acesso aos dados desse observable, você precisar dar um subscribe.

```
let prdn = queryProd('batata');

prdn.subscribe(data => {

    // data é o seu array
    for (let item of data) {
        console.log(item.algumDado);
    }
});
```